# Poner ceros en los extremos de una matriz java

Tags: java, matrices

Estoy creando un metodo que dada una matriz, ponga todo el marco lleno de ceros, es decir para la matriz

```
1   2  3  4
5   6  7  8
9  10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

la salida deberia ser

```
0  0  0 0
0  6  7 0
0 10 11 0 
0  0  0 0
```

Tengo este codigo:

```
public static void llenaCeros(int[][] matriz) {
        for (int i = 0; i <1; i++) { //fila 0
            for (int j = 0; j <= ladoh; j++) {
                matriz[i][j]=0;
                System.out.println(matriz[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

y me imprime una matriz de una columna llena de ceros, pero no el resto de la matriz.

Comment: espero mi respuesta te ayude :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí lo tienes, solo era validar que ponga a 0 cuando el índice de x es 0 o igual al tamaño de filas o cuando el índice de y es 0 o igual al tamaño de columnas:

```
public static void llenaCeros(int[][] matriz) {
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) { //fila 0
            for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
                if (i==0 || i == matriz.length-1 ||  j == 0 || j == matriz[i].length -1)
                    matriz[i][j]=0;
                System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+ " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```